# how to define a set of variables so the program responds in any of the items in a list is called, python3

Tags: python, list, if-statement, input, set

I create a list so if someones inputs any item from the list it will print the same.

```
lista = ["example", "example2"]
listb = ["exampleb", "example2b"]
choice = input()
if choice == lista[]:
    print("outputa")
elif choice == listb[]:
    print("outputb")
```

if the user types either example or example2 it will print outputa but if the user types exampleb or example2b it will print outputb.
Thanks

Comment: I don't see a question

Comment: the question is in the title, sorry i didnt include it in the main part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
if choice in lista:
    print("a")
elif choice in listb:
    print("b")
```

`

Comment: You are right, thanks i honestly havent thought of that. I will mark your question as a correct one

Comment: `in` is a really cool operator in Python, the thing which I like most about Python is that the code is like normal English speech :)

Answer (score 4):

```
lista = ["example", "example2"]
listb = ["exampleb", "example2b"]
choice = input()
if choice in lista:
    print("outputa")
elif choice in listb:
    print("outputb")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `in` operator [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) Python? Such that you'd write:

```
if choice in list_a:
    print("Output A")
elif choice in list_b:
    print("Output B")
```